# Yodlee error for Fastlink (Getting Production Token)

Tags: curl, yodlee

I am trying to integrate Yodlee with our app. I have done the steps in developer mode, but when I'm trying to get the token on production I'm getting this error, even though I am using the URL I have to use:

```
{
  "errorCode":"Y807",
  "errorMessage":"Resource not found",
  "referenceCode":"l1471989041498B11T131n"
}
```

I'm using the Yodlee API REST Endpoint, is it not that one?

Answer (score 0):

Please note- For production environment, we have a different base URL.

Once you subscribe for this service, you have to provide your IPs for whitelisting and using these IPs you will be  able to consume our services.

Regards,

Krithik